# $\text{cis } 75^\circ + \text{cis } 83^\circ + \text{cis } 91^\circ + \dots + \text{cis } 147^\circ$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The number
$\text{cis } 75^\circ + \text{cis } 83^\circ + \text{cis } 91^\circ + \dots + \text{cis } 147^\circ$
is expressed in the form $r \, \text{cis } \theta$, where $0 \le \theta < 360^\circ$. Find $\theta$ in degrees.

I tried to use this site for geometric sequences, [How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Let $\frac{75\pi}{180}=\alpha$. Since $\text{cis} \theta=e^{i \theta}$. Therefore the given series can be written as
$$e^{i \alpha}+e^{i \left(\alpha+\frac{8\pi}{180}\right)}+e^{i \left(\alpha+\frac{16\pi}{180}\right)}+ \dotsb + e^{i \left(\alpha+\frac{72\pi}{180}\right)}.$$
Let $\frac{8\pi}{180}=\beta$. Then we can write this as: 
$$e^{i \alpha}\left[1+e^{i \beta}+e^{i2\beta}+ \dotsb + e^{i 9\beta}\right].$$
This is a geometric series with common ratio $e^{i\beta}$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
   \text{cis }75^\circ +
      \text{cis }83^\circ +
      \text{cis }91^\circ + \dots +
      \text{cis }147^\circ
   &= \text{cis }75^\circ \left(
      1 +
      \text{cis }8^\circ +
      \text{cis }16^\circ + \dots +
      \text{cis }72^\circ \right)\\
   &= \text{cis }75^\circ \left(
      1 +
      \text{cis }8^\circ +
      (\text{cis }8^\circ)^2 + \dots +
      (\text{cis }8^\circ)^9 \right)\\
   &= \text{cis }75^\circ
      \dfrac{(\text{cis }8^\circ)^{10}-1}{\text{cis }8^\circ-1}\\
   &= \text{cis }75^\circ
      \dfrac{\text{cis }80^\circ-1}{\text{cis }8^\circ-1}\\
\end{align}